# How to navigate from UIView to UIViewController

Tags: objective-c

i am aware that uiview does not have navigational control. Thus, i am not able to push from the uiview to the next uiviewcontroller.

here is the code of my method. Please help. Thanks!

```
 - (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"%f , %f",pointInView.x,pointInView.y);

    if ((pointInView.x >= (231.0) && pointInView.x <=(293) && pointInView.y >= (193)  && pointInView.y <=(218)) )
    {

        // how to push to next viewcontroller here?

        UIView *view = [UIGestureRecognizer view]; //what should i do for this code?


        [self viewController];
    }
}

-(TestViewViewController*)viewController
{
    for (UIView *next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview)
    {
        UIResponder *nextResponder = [next nextResponder];

        if([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[TestViewViewController class]])
        {

            return (TestViewViewController*)nextResponder;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get viewcontroller having a view than you can use `nextResponder` method

So first you get the view from gestureRecognizer:

```
UIView *view = [gestureRecognizer view];
```

and than search for the viewcontroller containing the view

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309569/how-to-get-uiviewcontroller-of-a-uiviews-superview-in-iphone-sdk)

***Edit:***

```
 if ((pointInView.x >= (231.0) && pointInView.x <=(293) && pointInView.y >= (193)  && pointInView.y <=(218)) )
    {

        // how to push to next viewcontroller here?

        UIView *view = [recognizer view]; //what should i do for this code?

       UIViewController *viewController = [self getViewControllerFromView:view];

       if(viewController) {
          // do whatever you want...
         UIViewController *newViewController = ...
         [viewController.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
       }

    }
```

...
I rewrote method get ViewController to your case. To get it from some view:

```
-(UIViewController*)getViewControllerFromView:(UIView*) view
{
    if([[view nextResponder] isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
    {
        return (UIViewController*)[view nextResponder];
    }
    else {

        for (UIView *next = [view superview]; next; next = next.superview)
        {
            UIResponder *nextResponder = [next nextResponder];

            if([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
            {
                return (UIViewController*)nextResponder;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

**new edit::**

your `EAGLView` has `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *viewController;`
ADD `@synthesize viewController = _viewController;` to .m file.

CoreMotionAppDelegate::

```
MainViewController * itemsViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemsViewController];
    glView.viewController = itemsViewController;  


    [glView startAnimation];
    [[self window]setRootViewController:navController];
```

And than in your `scrollViewDoubleTapped` method just

```
EAGLView *v = (EAGLView*)[recognizer view];  
UIViewController *viewController =  v.viewController;
```

Comment: hi george, i edited the codes as you suggested but i'm not sure how to link the uiview to the responder. i edited the codes above. please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I see that you do not understand what you are doing at all. Wait i will edit the answer

Comment: Hi george. i added your codes in to my project and added this two lines of codes at the // do whatever you want area.


 TestViewViewController *newViewController = [[ TestViewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [viewController.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];


        }

but i ran into some error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIGestureRecognizer view]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3f342908'

please help. Thanks George!

Comment: my fault, because of writing a code in browser, replace [UIGestureRecognizer view]; to [recognizer view];

Comment: Hi George, I have added the above code, however I am still unable to push to a new UIViewController. My view = EAGL View contains a 3D model, when user touch a certain part of the model, it will link to the new UIViewController, is it possible to do this?

Comment: add log to if(viewController) {.. here } and say if it finds the viewcontroller

Comment: Hi George, I added a NSLog above the if(viewController) however, the program never read the NSLog. when i debug, i notice that my UIView *next at the  for (UIView *next = [view superview]; next; next = next.superview)  have an absurb value, it says (info = 1, value = 3574903). Is this the source of the problem? Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Do not know how to help. Share than a code, how you add the view and gesture recoginzer

Comment: Hey George, I have upload my codes in media fire, here is the link http://www.mediafire.com/?6d1v2rtva2n1uxe                              The codes that you have suggested is located in EAGL view.m. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi George,I accidentally deleted the file, here is the new link http://www.mediafire.com/?14cefzmi7f671vr. Thanks

Comment: I will look i half an hour

Comment: I edited how to get view controller, it gets it, but doesn't push

Comment: Hi George, for the scrollviewDoubleTap method, the EAGLView *v = (EAGLView*)[recognizer view];  
UIViewController *viewController =  v.viewController;                is this placed in the   if ((pointInView.x >= (231.0)  && pointInView.y >= (162)) )
Or we can just ignore it? and just place the code as you suggested above.