# How to access ParentViewController method from subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have created a method that calls a `UIViewController` and loads it as a `subview` like this

```
cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];
        cameraViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
        [cameraViewController drawCameraView:htmlProjID ProjectGUID:selectedProjGUID DoorGUID:cell.currentItem.doorGUID Info:nil doorName:cell.currentItem.doorDesc ViewName:@"Finishing"];
        [self.view addSubview:cameraViewController.view];
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to then access a method from `camerViewController`(subview) from the original `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this will return what you want to get:

```
 id mainViewController = [self.view.superview nextResponder];
```

Apple's documentation of -[UIResponder nextResponder]:

UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)

Other than this you can have idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309978/503317).

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. going to go read up on nextResponder I have been doing abit of work using delegates... i freaken hate delegates

Answer (score 1):

Define a `protocol` and use a `delegate` as per this answer...

[How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

NSNotifications are always handy in this situation. You simply define a observer in viewDidLoad of camerViewController:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(YourMethod:) name:@"YourNSNotificaitionName" object:nil];
```

and then you just post an NSNotication of that name from the original view:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourNSNotificaitionName" object:nil userInfo:Nil];
```

Which will call the appropriate method on the subview.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Public methods of the Subview class from `UIViewController`. But it sometimes might not work due some limitations.

You can use Protocol to implement such things. For that follow this :

- Declare the protocol from which ViewController you want call the method
- Call the method of subview by using delegate protocol

Other way to perform it is to create that method into AppDelegate file & call from it.